# carregar processo independente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com problemas para carregar processos a partir de uma aplicação python.

Antes eu estava usando o **subprocess.Popen**, mas ele cria subprocessos da aplicação principal, e no meu caso, preciso criar processos que rodem independentes, no sentido de que, se minha aplicação venha cair, os processos não caiam.

Outra necessidade é recuperar o PID do processo - por essa razão não estou usando o **os.system()**.

Fiz testes com o **os.spawnl()**, mas não obtive sucesso.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

segue o código onde testei o *os.spawnl()*

```
>>> import os
>>> programa = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\mongoDB\bin\mongod.exe'
>>> parametros = r'--logpath "C:\Foo\Bar\Base\install.log" --dbpath "C:\Foo\Bar\Base\data\db" --port 1124'
>>> os.path.dirname(programa)
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mongoDB\\bin'
>>> os.path.basename(programa)
'mongod.exe'
>>> os.spawnl(os.P_WAIT, os.path.dirname(programa), os.path.basename(programa), parametros)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    os.spawnl(os.P_WAIT, os.path.dirname(programa), os.path.basename(programa), parametros)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\os.py", line 922, in spawnl
    return spawnv(mode, file, args)
>>> os.spawnl(os.P_WAIT, "%s %s".format(programa, parametros))
#aqui ocorre crash no pythonw
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
import platform
import subprocess

def carregar_processo(cmd):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
        return subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP).pid
    else:
        return subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).pid
```

Answer (score 0):

No Windows, dá para usar a função [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile). Assim:

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\Windows\Notepad.exe')
```

Se você estiver precisando de uma solução independente de plataforma, [dê uma olhada nesse link (inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317219/is-there-an-platform-independent-equivalent-of-os-startfile).

Comment: Olá Michael, obrigado pelo comentário, infelizmente essa solução não me atende por não retornar o PID da aplicação